# Create a new column based on the value arrangement of another column in R dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a data frame that looks like this:

I want to create a new column called `labels`, which indicates the genes that have the
top2 **positive** `log2FoldChange` and small `pvalue` as well
as the top2 **negative** `log2FoldChange` and small `pvalue`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(gene=c("AT1G23410","AT2G05530","AT2G26820","AT1G36240","AT5G05260","AT5G47260"), 
       log2FoldChange=c(14.468018,13.763999,13.708055, -13.480280,-12.166529,-11.468673), 
       pvalue=c(0.001,0.004,0.005,0.0041,0.0034,0.004))

df
#> # A tibble: 6 × 3
#>   gene      log2FoldChange pvalue
#>   <chr>              <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1 AT1G23410           14.5 0.001 
#> 2 AT2G05530           13.8 0.004 
#> 3 AT2G26820           13.7 0.005 
#> 4 AT1G36240          -13.5 0.0041
#> 5 AT5G05260          -12.2 0.0034
#> 6 AT5G47260          -11.5 0.004
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

I want my data to look like this.

```
#>   gene      log2FoldChange pvalue labels
#>   <chr>              <dbl>  <dbl> 
#> 1 AT1G23410           14.5 0.001   AT1G23410
#> 2 AT2G05530           13.8 0.004   AT2G05530
#> 3 AT2G26820           13.7 0.005 
#> 4 AT1G36240          -13.5 0.0041  AT1G36240
#> 5 AT5G05260          -12.2 0.0034  AT5G05260
#> 6 AT5G47260          -11.5 0.004
```

**EDIT:**
by small pvalue I mean the smallest value in the dataset. In terms of arrange it would be: 
`arrange(log2FoldChange, pvalue)` for the negative ones, and for the positive `arrange(desc(log2FoldChange), pvalue)`
does it make sense

Comment: what do you mean by small pvalue?

Comment: Thank you @Mäel, by small pvalue, I mean the smallest in combination with the smallest log2FoldChange. In terms of arranging it would be: `arrange(log2FoldChange, pvalue)` for the negative ones, and for the positive `arrange(desc(log2FoldChange), pvalue)` does it make sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `arrange` and use `ifelse`:

```r
df %>% 
  arrange(log2FoldChange) %>% 
  mutate(labels = ifelse(row_number() %in% c(1:2, (n()-1):n()), gene, ""))
```

output

```r
# A tibble: 6 × 4
  gene      log2FoldChange pvalue labels     
  <chr>              <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>      
1 AT1G36240          -13.5 0.0041 "AT1G36240"
2 AT5G05260          -12.2 0.0034 "AT5G05260"
3 AT5G47260          -11.5 0.004  ""         
4 AT2G26820           13.7 0.005  ""         
5 AT2G05530           13.8 0.004  "AT2G05530"
6 AT1G23410           14.5 0.001  "AT1G23410"
```

---

If there is a filtering to do with `pvalue`, you can do:

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(labels = ifelse(log2FoldChange %in% c(head(log2FoldChange[order(log2FoldChange, pvalue)], 2),
                                               head(log2FoldChange[order(-log2FoldChange, pvalue)], 2)), gene, ""))
```

Comment: oo come on, this is beautiful!

Comment: could something like this work @Maël

`mutate(labels = ifelse(log2FoldChange %in% c(head(arrange(log2FoldChange, pvalue), 2),
                                               tail(arrange(log2FoldChange, pvalue), 2))), gene, "")`

I am aware that this one is wrong, but that's the logic I was thinking for to work in my bigdataset

Comment: Check edit, you can use `order` to order based on two columns.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an option:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df <- tibble(gene=c("AT1G23410","AT2G05530","AT2G26820","AT1G36240","AT5G05260","AT5G47260"), 
             log2FoldChange=c(14.468018,13.763999,13.708055, -13.480280,-12.166529,-11.468673), 
             pvalue=c(0.001,0.004,0.005,0.0041,0.0034,0.004))

df %>% left_join(
df %>% 
  mutate(positive = ifelse(log2FoldChange >= 0, "y", "n")) %>% 
  split(.$positive) %>% 
  map(~.x %>% arrange(desc(abs(log2FoldChange))) %>% slice(1:2) %>% select(gene) %>% mutate(labels = gene)) %>% 
  bind_rows())
#> Joining, by = "gene"
#> # A tibble: 6 × 4
#>   gene      log2FoldChange pvalue labels   
#>   <chr>              <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>    
#> 1 AT1G23410           14.5 0.001  AT1G23410
#> 2 AT2G05530           13.8 0.004  AT2G05530
#> 3 AT2G26820           13.7 0.005  <NA>     
#> 4 AT1G36240          -13.5 0.0041 AT1G36240
#> 5 AT5G05260          -12.2 0.0034 AT5G05260
#> 6 AT5G47260          -11.5 0.004  <NA>
```

Comment: thank you Matt, it looks very cool

Answer (score 1):

You can `arrange` the data and `label` first and last 2 rows.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  arrange(desc(log2FoldChange)) %>%
  mutate(label = case_when(row_number() %in% c(1, 2, n()-1, n()) ~ gene, 
                           TRUE ~ ""))

#  gene      log2FoldChange pvalue label      
#  <chr>              <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>      
#1 AT1G23410           14.5 0.001  "AT1G23410"
#2 AT2G05530           13.8 0.004  "AT2G05530"
#3 AT2G26820           13.7 0.005  ""         
#4 AT5G47260          -11.5 0.004  ""         
#5 AT5G05260          -12.2 0.0034 "AT5G05260"
#6 AT1G36240          -13.5 0.0041 "AT1G36240"
```

*Note - It is not clear to me what you mean by small p-value. This answer only considers `log2FoldChange` variable which seems to match with your expected output.*

Comment: Thank you, Ronak! That's a great point. In terms of arrange it would be 
`arrange(log2FoldChange, pvalue)` for the negative ones, and for the positive 
`arrange(desc(log2FoldChange), pvalue)`

does it make sense?

Answer (score 1):

A base R approach using `order()` only, and some indexing

```
df$labels <- NA
df[order(df$log2FoldChange),][1:2,]$labels <- df[order(df$log2FoldChange),][1:2,]$gene
df[order(df$log2FoldChange, decreasing = TRUE),][1:2,]$labels <- df[order(df$log2FoldChange, decreasing = TRUE),][1:2,]$gene
df
# A tibble: 6 × 4
  gene      log2FoldChange pvalue labels   
  <chr>              <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>    
1 AT1G23410           14.5 0.001  AT1G23410
2 AT2G05530           13.8 0.004  AT2G05530
3 AT2G26820           13.7 0.005  NA       
4 AT1G36240          -13.5 0.0041 AT1G36240
5 AT5G05260          -12.2 0.0034 AT5G05260
6 AT5G47260          -11.5 0.004  NA
```